# Issue with adding/removing/changing CSS classes on hover with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to show this span tag on hover (i.e. CSS display: inline) and when the mouse leaves, I want to hide it (i.e. CSS display: none). I want to do this with AngularJS directives.

This is my HTML snippet:

```
<span class="" ng-class="{show: hover, hide: !hover}" ng-init="hover = false" ng-mouseenter="hover = true" ng-mouseleave="hover = false">The text that I want to show/hide</span>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.show{
  display: inline;
}
.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

For some reason, when I do this, nothing happens. The span element starts out hidden (which is correct) but remains hidden when i hover my mouse over it. Does anybody know what is wrong with my code? Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: You can't hover over hidden element. You need to set `visibility:visible/hidden;`

Comment: Why not css only? Why 2 classes? wouldn't "hide" or "show" be enough? Anyway it's hidden, so it can't receive any pointer-events. Try visibility instead (which actually still gives you the elements dimension, sou you have something to hover on)

Comment: once spam has hide class it’s hidden from dom the you can’t perform mouseevent.

Comment: And what @lexith say is very true. Better to use a class and handle everything from the css: `<span class="hover-visible">Content</span>` and then you just need this: `.hover-visible { visibility:hidden; } .hover-visible:hover { visibility:visible; }`

Comment: Got it thanks! The span class is actually a child of an anchor tag and I should have placed the 'ng-init="hover = false" ng-mouseenter="hover = true" ng-mouseleave="hover = false"' on that anchor tag instead.  My bad, thanks for your help!

Comment: @SteveD. So you can also do it using css only (Better performance-wise) `<div class="wrapper><span class="child">Content</span></div>` and css: `.wrapper .child { display: none; } .wrapper:hover .child { display: inline; }`

Comment: @AlonEitan Yes. I don't know why I didn't think of that in the first place. Thanks!